# How can I connect to a Cassandra cluster running in Docker?

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra

I am using `bitnami/cassandra` docker image for `cassandra`. I guess it is starting also, but I am not sure how to connect `cassandra` through any GUI or tool.

What is the host for cassandra? I tried `localhost` and container name but not able to connect. I tried checking `cassandra.yml` file from docker container and `listen_address` is something alphanumeric value. What would be the public ip so I can connect through GUI or `cqlsh`.

How can I configure public IP or `listen_address` in `cassandra.yml` file or after starting cassandra docker container how can I connect it through GUI or any code.

Below is my `docker-compose`

```
  cassandra:
    image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
    container_name: "cassandra"
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '9042:9042' # native protocol clients
    volumes:
      - ./data/cassandra:/bitnami
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_USER=user
      - CASSANDRA_PASS=password
      - CASSANDRA_CQL_PORT_NUMBER=9042
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
```

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any issues connecting to a Cassandra container running the Bitnami image.

You didn't provide details of what your issue was or steps to replicate the problems so I'm going to provide the steps I did in the hope that it will help you.

**STEP 1** - Pull the Bitnami Cassandra Docker image:

```
$ docker pull bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

**STEP 2** - Create a bridged network called `cass-network`:

```
$ docker network create cass-network --driver bridge
```

**STEP 3** - Launch the Cassandra instance called `bitnamicassandra`:

```
$ docker run --rm -d \
    --name bitnamicassandra \
    -p 9042:9042 \
    --hostname bitnamicassandra \
    --network cass-network \
    bitnami/cassandra
```

**STEP 4** - Connect to the container to watch the Cassandra `system.log` and wait for startup to complete, specifically waiting for the node to listen for CQL connections:

```
INFO  [main] 2023-02-10 05:45:01,138 PipelineConfigurator.java:126 - \
    Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)...
```

Since I've exposed the CQL port (with `--port 9042:9042`), I can see on my Docker host that the port is mapped as I expected:

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN | grep dock
com.docke 51936          erick   85u  IPv6 0xddbfea4aa7f1e44f      0t0  TCP *:9042 (LISTEN)
com.docke 51969          erick   21u  IPv4 0xddbfea4ba2125bef      0t0 ICMP *:*
```

NOTE: You can also use the Linux command `netstat -tnlp`.

**STEP 5** - Connect to Cassandra using cqlsh:

```
$ cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connected to My Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.1.0 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

If you update your original question with:

- steps to replicate your issue,
- full command you ran, and
- full error message,

I'd be happy to review it.

For more info + examples, see the [Bitnami Cassandra image page on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra/). Cheers!